# Sharepoint list view threshold maximum limit?

Tags: list-view-threshold

I have a client who has already exceeded default sharepoint threshold. [image]

Is understand that it is not advisable to increase the default limit but in my case i am left with no other option than to increase the threshold .

Can anyone tell me what is the **max limit** for threshold i can put? Client is expecting another 50000 files going into the document store.

As per [this](http://office2010.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/manage-lists-and-libraries-with-many-items-HA010378155.aspx?redir=0) it says max limit is 50 million. How much can i increase it to? any guidance on this will be very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The threshold has nothing to do with how many items can be in a library. It has to do with the performance of the views.  So, keep  the threshold low, and configure views to only show a small number of items at a time, like items added today (and index the fields you're using to filter the views).

If you increase the view threshold anyway, you're going to have significant performance problems on your site.

Comment: Also, when creating a view based on an Indexed field, that field *must* be the first one listed in the filters.  If it isn't then SharePoint will still show the Threshold Warning message

Answer (score 2):

As @Mike2500 points out, changing the threshold is not advisable but there are other alternatives to handling this, such as folder organization, key fields and so forth.  This ["Training Course" from Microsoft](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/introduction-RZ101874361.aspx?section=2) is one of the best resources that I've run across on how to handle the Large List issue and should provide you with a few options that might work in your situation as well as an understanding of the underlying issue itself