# Limit in a Sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online

I've a list near of 5000 elements (Limit is 5000 elements), my question is. "Can I increase capacity over 5000 elements in SharePoint 2010 ??

Answer (score 1):

Even though the List View Threshold could be changed, it is strongly recommended do not follow this way, since it has performance implications.

Instead, consider other ways to store large list, for example:

- Reorganize repository (create folder structure, store across multiple list, sites, or site collections)
- Utilize archiving

Refer an article [Designing large lists and maximizing list performance (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262813%28v=office.14%29.aspx) for a details

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are misunderstanding the term 'view threshold'.  The view threshold is not a hard limit on the maximum number of items a list can have.  Instead, it is a hard limit on the maximum number of items that will be returned for a given view or query.  The hard limit on number of items per list is around 30 million (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx#ListLibrary).

However, you can use techniques such as indexes, metadata navigation, and keyfilters to work around the view threshold:

[How can I configure a View filter/index to go around the item threshold?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/71495/how-can-i-configure-a-view-filter-index-to-go-around-the-item-threshold)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee559293.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262813%28v=office.14%29.aspx#SharePoint2010

Answer (score 0):

> Open the SharePoint Central Administration, go to Application
>   Management --> Manage Web Applications Click to select the web
>   application that hosts your list (eg. SharePoint - 80) At the Ribbon,
>   select the General Settings and select Resource Throttling Then, you
>   can see the 5000 List View Threshold limit and you can edit the value
>   you want. Click OK to save it.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093955/exceeds-the-list-view-threshold-5000-items-in-sharepoint-2010

Comment: And also, this is the List View threshold, by using filtering in your views you can keep going without changing the Threshold value. For example only show items newer than x days, or with a certain status etc.